# Get size from widget init

Tags: python, kivy

How can I find out the size of the screen (widget in this case) from the init of the widget? Below there are two print functions: one returns a default widget size, the other returns the real size of the widget.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.config import Config

class MyScreen(Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreen, self).__init__ (**kwargs)
        self.size_hint = 1, 1
        print self.size #returns 100, 100

    def on_touch_down(self, *ignore):
        print self.size #returns real size for the screen 1280 800

class TemplateApp(App):
    Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')

    def build(self):
        return MyScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    TemplateApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Both return the correct result, the widget size *is* `100, 100` during the `__init__`. It is updated later by its parent, in this case the Window itself.

If you care about size changes, bind a function to its size that does whatever updating you need.

Comment: thanks for taking the time mate, binding to size, returns 3 values, something like this: [0.0, 100]
[1170.0, 100]
[1170.0, 800] I only need the last value, but instead I get the first one. Not sure I did the correct thing though.. I used on_size to print the size value